# Custom validation for profile type?

Tags: forms

I used `profile2 module` and create some profile types,in one of them I have a custom field require custom validation .
I did use drupal validation with custom validation function .
Lets suppose  I have a field with name  'nationalcode' if it was form element just need this in my custom module hook_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state)

```
$form['field_nationalcode']['#validation'][] = 'my_custom_validation_function';
```

And determine **my_custom_validation_function** function with my custom validation

```
function my_custom_validation_function(&$form,&$form_state) {
  if(!mycustomvalidation)
     form_set_error('field_nationalcode','my custom message');
        // I am not sure mayebe this one
     form_set_error('nationalcode','my custom message');
 }
```

But really what I should do in profile type cusotm validation?

I  set `#validation`  but How can i set form_set_error with profile type? .I means what i should  use in first parameter in `form_set_error` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found The good solution for validate nested form elements
according to [drupal 7 form_set_error api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) need to use

```
form_set_error('myporifletypename][myfieldname', 'my error message');
```

As example

```
 form_set_error('user_info][field_nationalcode', 'Your National code not valid');
```